# Samsung Galaxy P1000 image folder

Tags: android

i'm using Samsung Galaxy P1000 tab,my problem is galaxy tab always takes images from drawable-hdpi.if scale those images then images have pixelated and if make 600*1024 resolution image then problem is how can recognize  two images with same name in same folder of hdpi(tab+hdpi images) then how can i put images of tab in android drawable folder